# continuous random number in teradata

Tags: teradata

This works fine:

```
SELECT    RANDOM(0,1)
```

but produces an integer (0 or 1). Is it possible to obtain continuous random numbers in teradata (i.e. uniformly distributed number between zero and one inclusively)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this UDF (or just the calculation):

```
REPLACE FUNCTION Rand_01() /* 0 <= r <= 1 */
RETURNS FLOAT
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
   ((CAST(RANDOM(-2147483648, 2147483647) AS FLOAT) + 2147483648) / 4294967295);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found a possible answer:

```
SELECT    CAST(RANDOM(0,999999999) AS FLOAT)/1000000000
```

Taken from [here](http://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/How-to-generate-random-integer-numbers-by-using-a-function/td-p/13770).

Comment: This might return a somewhat biased random value, better use the full range of intergers.